# @Transactional service methods rollback hibernate changes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a method inside a @Service class which calls two different methods in two different @Service classes. These two different methods save two entities inside the database (through hibernate) and they both may throw some exceptions. 
I would like that if an exception is thrown, independently from which @Service method, all the changes are rolled back. So all the entities created inside the database are deleted.

```
//entities
@Entity
public class ObjectB{
   @Id
   private long id;
   ...
}

@Entity
public class ObjectC{
   @Id
   private long id;
   ...
}



//servicies
@Service
@Transactional
public class ClassA{

   @Autowired
   private ClassB classB;

   @Autowired
   private ClassC classC;

   public void methodA(){
      classB.insertB(new ObjectB());
      classC.insertC(new ObjectC());
   }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class ClassB{

   @Autowired
   private RepositoryB repositoryB;

   public void insertB(ObjectB b){
      repositoryB.save(b);
   }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class ClassC{

   @Autowired
   private RepositoryC repositoryC;

   public void insertC(ObjectC c){
      repositoryC.save(c);
   }
}


//repositories
@Repository
public interface RepositoryB extends CrudRepository<ObjectB, String>{
}

@Repository
public interface RepositoryC extends CrudRepository<ObjectC, String>{
}
```

I would like that methodA of ClassA, once an exception has been thrown from either methodB or methodC, it rollbacks all the changes inside the database.
But it doesn't do that. All the changes remains after the exception...
What am I missing?
What should I add in order to make it work as I want?
I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.6!
I haven't configured anything in particular to make the transactions work!

---

**EDIT 1**

This is my main class if it can help:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JobWebappApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(JobWebappApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobWebappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When an exception is thrown this is what I see in the console:

```
Completing transaction for [com.example.ClassB.insertB]
Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@31d4fbf4] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@df9d400] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@1d1ad46b] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
Getting transaction for [com.example.ClassC.insertC]
Completing transaction for [com.example.ClassC.insertC] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: runtime exception!
Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: runtime exception!
Winning rollback rule is: null
No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
Completing transaction for [com.example.ClassA.methodA] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: runtime exception!
Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: runtime exception!
Winning rollback rule is: null
No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
Clearing transaction synchronization
Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@1d1ad46b] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@31d4fbf4] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@df9d400] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: runtime exception!] with root cause
```

It seems that each time it calls a method it creates a new transaction! Is without rolling back anything after RuntimeException occurs!

---

**EDIT 2**

This is the pom.xml dependencies file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampleDB?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.locationId.new_generator_mappings=false
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @M.Deinum I found the solution!

I was using a wrong database engine (MyISAM), which does not support transaction! So I changed the table engine type with "InnoDB" which supports transactions. What I did is this:

1. I added this property inside application.properties file, inorder to tell to JPA which was the engine type it should use to "manipulate" the tables:

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

2. I dropped all the existing tables (with the wrong engine type) inside my DB and I let JPA to recreate all of them with the right engine (InnoDB).

Now all the RuntimeExceptions thrown make the transaction to rollback all the changes done within it.

ALERT: I noticed that if an exception which is not a subclass of RuntimeException is thrown, no rollback is applied and all the changes already done remain inside the database.

Comment: make sure the `@Transactional` is `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` but not `javax.transaction.Transactional` ?

Comment: @KenChan thanks man! You are right! I had all the imports wrong... now I’m gonna change all of them and test it again!

Comment: Should work just like that .

Comment: @Stefano. Thanks. Let me know if it work or not. If it works , how about I change my comment into answer and you accept it and give it a vote up if you can ? 

Comment: Nothing... it still doesn't work! Basically what happens is that insertC throws an exception but b of type ObcjectB does not get deleted from the database.

Comment: Is it maybe due to a wrong configuration of the transaction manager?

Comment: Please add your configuration (both java and properties/yaml) also please specify which database you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum done! Check it out!

Comment: Remove the `spring-test` dependency (that is alrady included in the `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency). You are using MYSQL make sure tha tyou are using MySQL with InnoDB tables and not with MyISAM tables. The latter don't support transactions.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you very much. I updated the question with the solution you proposed. I think it was the wrong database table engine. Once I changed to InnoDB it worked just fine! The only problem is that only the RuntimeException (and subclasses) trigger the rollback. If an exception which extends just Throwable is thrown, it doesn't trigger the rollback! Is it a correct behavior?

Comment: Yes that is the expected behavior, this same behavior comes from EJBs. This is also documented as the expected behavior and also how you can modify it.

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to achieve should work out of the box. Check your spring configuration.

Make sure you created `TransactionManager` bean and make sure you placed [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) annotation on some of your spring `@Configuration`s. This annotation are responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power annotation-driven transaction management, such as the `TransactionInterceptor` and the proxy- or AspectJ-based advice that weave the interceptor into the call stack when `@Transactional` methods are invoked.

See the linked documentation.

If you are using `spring-boot` it should [automatically](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2376f973f41053bd82724ba54c204baa59b268cc/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionAutoConfiguration.java#L82) add this annotation for you if you have `PlatformTransactionManager` class on classpath.

Also, please note that **checked exceptions does not trigger a rollback of the transaction**. Only runtime exceptions and errors trigger a rollback. You can, of course, configure this behavior with the `rollbackFor` and `noRollbackFor` annotation parameters.

**Edit**

As you clarified that you are using spring-boot, the answer is: all should work without any configuration.

Here is minimal 100% working example for spring-boot version `2.1.3.RELEASE` (but should work with any version ofc):

Dependencies:

```
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2') // or any other SQL DB supported by Hibernate
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok') // for getters, setters, toString
```

User entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}
```

Book entity:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User author;

    private String title;
}
```

User repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Book repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
}
```

User service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@Component
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
//        return userRepository.save(user);
        userRepository.save(user);
        throw new RuntimeException("User not saved");
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Book service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@Component
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public Book saveBook(Book book) {
        return bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Composite service:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Component
public class CompositeService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    public void saveUserAndBook() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John Smith");
        user = userService.saveUser(user);

        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor(user);
        book.setTitle("Mr Robot");
        bookService.saveBook(book);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JpaMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(JpaMain.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .properties("logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE")
                .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(CompositeService compositeService, UserService userService, BookService bookService) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                compositeService.saveUserAndBook();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
            }

            System.out.println("All users: " + userService.findAll());
            System.out.println("All books: " + bookService.findAll());
        };
    }
}
```

If you run the main method you should see that no books or users found in DB. The transaction is rolled back. If you remove the `throw new RuntimeException("User not saved")` line from `UserService`, both entities will be saved fine.

Also you should see the logs of `org.springframework.transaction` package on `TRACE` level, where for instance you will see:

```
Getting transaction for [demo.jpa.CompositeService.saveUserAndBook]
```

And then after exception is thrown:

```
Completing transaction for [demo.jpa.CompositeService.saveUserAndBook] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: User not saved
Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: User not saved
Winning rollback rule is: null
No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
Clearing transaction synchronization
```

Here `No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules` means that rules defined by [`DefaultTransactionAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/DefaultTransactionAttribute.html) will be applied to determine if transaction should be rolled back. And these rules are:

> Rolls back on runtime, but not checked, exceptions by default.

`RuntimeException` is runtime exception, so the transaction will be rolled back.

The line `Clearing transaction synchronization` is where rollback is actually applied. You will see some other `Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback` messages because `@Transactional` methods are nested here (`UserService.saveUser` called from `CompositeService.saveUserAndBook` and both methods are `@Transactional`), but all they do is determine rules for future actions (at the point of transaction synchronization). The actual rollback will be done only once, at the outermost `@Transactional` method exit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... I‘ve specified I’m using spring boot! What should I add of what you said? Only PlatformTransactionManager? Where and how?

Comment: If you are using `spring-boot`, all should work without any configuration. Make sure you added `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and your selected jdbc driver (e.g. `com.h2database:h2`). No configuration actually required. I'll update the answer to include some minimal working example.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it seems that I'm doing exactly the same things. I updated my questions adding what the console tells me after the exception is thrown. 
Is there a reason why you used @Component annotation for business logic classes instead of @Service?

Comment: Your log message shows that all works fine. Transaction should be rolled back. How do you determine that it isn't? How do you call `ClassA.methodA()` method? I suggest you to create a new project with minimal setup (e.g. using code from my answer), make sure it works and then incrementally change it to yours until it stops working. I can't guess what else can be wrong in you code, as it looks fine. About `@Component` and `@Service` - they are interchangeable.

Comment: Inside the database remain all the information created! I’m calling methodA from the controller!

Answer (score 0):

Since spring 3.1 if you're using spring-data-* or spring-tx dependencies on the classpath, then transaction management will be enabled by default.

> https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

But checking Springs Transactional annotation we can see that you'll need to inform the parameter rollbackFor if exception thown isn't a extension of RuntimeException.

```
/**
 * Defines zero (0) or more exception {@link Class classes}, which must be
 * subclasses of {@link Throwable}, indicating which exception types must cause
 * a transaction rollback.
 * <p>By default, a transaction will be rolling back on {@link RuntimeException}
 * and {@link Error} but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions). See
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute#rollbackOn(Throwable)}
 * for a detailed explanation.
 * <p>This is the preferred way to construct a rollback rule (in contrast to
 * {@link #rollbackForClassName}), matching the exception class and its subclasses.
 * <p>Similar to {@link org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RollbackRuleAttribute#RollbackRuleAttribute(Class clazz)}.
 * @see #rollbackForClassName
 * @see org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.DefaultTransactionAttribute#rollbackOn(Throwable)
 */
Class<? extends Throwable>[] rollbackFor() default {};
```

A simple **@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)** should work

Answer (score -2):

The thing that you are trying to achieve here is not possible, as once you come out of the method after executing it; changes can not be reverted as you have @Transactional annotation.

Alternatively you could set auto commit false, and write a try catch block in methodA of class A. And if there is no exception commit the DB transaction, or else don't.

Comment: All the transactional methods are contained in a single transaction due to the top-level `@Transactional`.